# файл Python не запускается в vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

в vs code не запускается пайтон
в терминале пишет вот это :
"cmd" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
[image: Вот скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

во первых команды cmd не существует. Во вторых терминал это и есть cmd. Что бы вызвать файл с расширением .py в терминале надо написать "python <название файла.py>" и тогда файл будет запущен